# Sometime I get Stream Closed sometimes i don't. Why do i get this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I have a chunk of code like this:

```
AxiomSoapMessage message = (AxiomSoapMessage)webServiceMessage; 

SoapHeader soapHeader = message.getSoapHeader();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = message.getAxiomMessage();
    
TransportContext transContext = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();

HttpServletConnection connection = (HttpServletConnection)transContext.getConnection();
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = connection.getHttpServletRequest();
    
InputStream inputStream = httpRequest.getInputStream();

SniffedXmlInputStream sniffedXmlInputStream = new SniffedXmlInputStream(inputStream);

String encoding = sniffedXmlInputStream.getXmlEncoding();
sniffedXmlInputStream.close();
    
String soapVersion = message.getVersion().toString();       
    
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    
**soapMessage.serialize(baos);** //THIS LINE
```

This is a part of a class which receives a Spring ws's **WebServiceMessage** from which I extract the **SOAPMessage** as shown above.

At the line in bold, marked with "THIS LINE" in the above code, I "sometimes" get the following exception

```
 org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: 
    org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: 
       javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: 
          ParseError at [row,col]:[1,4090] Message: Stream closed
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException could be happening due to invalid XML. Print the XML and see if it validates against the DTD or XSD.

Comment: I tried that too, but xml is valid. any more suggestions?
Earlier, instead of using ByteArrayOutputStream, i was using Apache's XmlStreamWriter and things were fine back then, but now i am getting this exception, occasionally.

Comment: I changed my code to using **SaajSoapMessage** instead of **AxiomSoapMessage**  and it is working. I don't know why but I'd be glad to know. Any comments?

Comment: SAAJ stands for Soap with Attachments API for Java. Does your XML have attachments?

Comment: I know what SAAJ stands for. Yes,i t contains Inline Attachments. Anyways, its done. Thank you!